# Visual Studio 2015 Build Tools missing DNX

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I've installed Visual Studio 2015 Build Tools onto our TeamCity server but the DNX folder is missing from within its installation root.

MSBuild 14 won't build an `xproj` because it imports `Microsoft.DNX.targets`

I've installed the latest DNX via the DNVM but it didn't create the DNX folder I was hoping it would.

The folder is obviously there on my dev box with VS2015 installed. I guess I could install the VS Community Edition, but why would the build tools be missing a crucial component??

Comment: It is not nearly as crucial as it seems, CoreCLR was in early beta and is changing rapidly.  Now you know, did this comment made you do anything differently?

Comment: The build tools package only contains MSBuild. For all other things you need to download separate installers. For DNX, either you download and install ASP.NET bits or build from source on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now the DNX MSBuild targets are only installed with Visual Studio 2015 (specifically the Web Development Tools component).

https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2207#issuecomment-120076364

So it looks like I'll have to install Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on the build server.

People are saying I should be using `dnu` from the command line, but the issue is that I need to make an MSDeploy package, and AFAIK, only MSBuild can do this.

Looks like I need to read this.

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html